# How to plot a figure using the data from dictionary of dictionary in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, plot, iteration, julia

I would like to plot a chart using the details from a nested dictionary.
For Example, I have a Dictionary like this:

```
d = Dict(:a => Dict(:val1 => rand(10), :val2 => rand(50)),
    :b => Dict(:val1 => rand(40), :val2 => rand(60)))
```

I would like to create a violin plot such that for each key like `:a` & `:b` the `:val1` represents violin plot and `:val2` represents scatter plot. (The figure should be a single plot, created using modifier functions(plot!)).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
julia> using StatsPlots

julia> d = Dict(:a => Dict(:val1 => rand(10), :val2 => rand(50)),
           :b => Dict(:val1 => rand(40), :val2 => rand(60)));

julia> p = plot();

julia> for k ∈ keys(d)
           violin!(d[k][:val1], label = string(k))
           scatter!(d[k][:val2], label = string(k))
       end

julia> current()
```

[image]

I'll be the first to admit that this is an awful plot, but I can't really picture from your question what you're looking for here exactly - in any case the above shows the basic idea of how to iterate through your nested dict and generate `scatter` and `violin` plots, hopefully you can customise this to do what you need!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, hahah I agree it is really awful. Disadvantage of using `rand()`. But highly appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I wanted to access the values from the dictionary and use them for plotting but my syntax of accessing them was wrong. As the original dictionary comprises of huge data values coming from ML predictions. However, Thanks for showing the correct way to access these values.